# How to remove (YYYY) from date-string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, date

I am  making a function that remembers a users birthday, and im storing the birthdate in my database in this format "08/12/1988".

Now how do I remove the "YYYY", so that I end up with only day and month? 08/12

Because that would allow me to make a if statement like this:

**THIS DIDN'T WORK:**

```
$date_today = date("d-m");

if($string_from_db_without_year == $date_today){
   echo"Congrats, it's your birthday!";
}
```

**THIS WORKED:**

```
    $string_from_db = $bruger_info_profil['birthday'];
    $date = strtotime($string_from_db);
    $converted_date_from_db = date('m/d',$date);

        echo $converted_date_from_db;
```

Comment: Is that date format `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Comment: DD/MM/YYYY - danish/european timeformat :-)

Comment: Are you really storing the date in your database in a varchar column?

Comment: yes? whats wrong with that?

Comment: What's wrong is that it adds complexity if you want to do something like "show users with birthdays this week/month" at some point.... your database provides a perfectly good date/time datatype for handling dates, that simplifies a lot of "range" or "formatting" based queries, while if you use varchar then you'll need to do anything like that "the hard way" in the future

Comment: Im building a big public forum from scratch, with full functionality. And this is a function that i will only use once in my source. So i doubt that a silly birthday-function will be the hardest part of my project ;)

Comment: and yet you are here asking how to do it.

Comment: programming is a bit like football.. When you're not training, you hang out with your soccer-friends, and discuss which techniques and strategey are the best in which situations. And you watch football-matches on the TV all the time, to see how the pro's are playing! You know in theory what makes THEM a good player, but you can't play like them in real life ;) That's how i feel about programming. LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = strtotime('08/12/1988');
echo date('d/m',$date);
?>
```

Comment: Just had to switch date('d/m',$date) to date('m/d',$date) .. For some reason :D

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$input  = '08/12/1988';
$output = date('d-m', strtotime($input));
```

Comment: But will that output `8-December`, or `12-August`?

Comment: `strtotime` assumes `MM/DD/YYYY` because of the slashes so `12-08`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = strtotime( "08/12/1988");
$birthday = date("d-m", $time);
```

Or

```
list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', "08/12/1988");
$birthday = $day.'-'.$month;
```